# how to iterate through a listbox selected items and get ValueMember and Display Member

Tags: c#, listbox, selecteditem, listboxitems

Hello I am trying to iterate through the selected items of a listbox in winforms like this:

```
foreach (ListBox item in sknBox.SelectedItems)            
{              
    Console.WriteLine(item.ValueMember);
    Console.WriteLine(item.DisplayMember);     
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox'.

Is there a way to fix this? or another straight forward solution?

Comment: ValueMember and DisplayMember are properties tied to the ListBox as a whole, not to a single item.

Comment: and, you can always get the items' properties that equals `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`. first convert `SomeClass obj = item as SomeClass `

Comment: You can't get whole ListBoxes from the SelectedItems property of one ListBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message it is clear that the `.SelectedItems` is a collection of `System.Data.DataRowView`, so you can access the required values through `Row` with indexers as like the following:

```
foreach (var item in sknBox.SelectedItems)            
{              
    Console.WriteLine(((DataRowView)item).Row["Value-member-name-here"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(((DataRowView)item).Row["Display-member-name-here"].ToString());     
}
```

Comment: It won't work like that, but the approach is close, see my answer

Comment: There was a problem casting item to DataRowView

Comment: @ForgacsNorbert: I don't get what you mean, Take a look into your answer as well the same process is happening there

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found #are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: your code. If you want to feel free to run it before

Comment: @ForgacsNorbert: oh..! I missed a bracket there, thanks bro its fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I think the type of item should be the type of the Element of sknBox.SelectedItems.
I afraid that your sknBox will not  contain other ListBoxes.
Or just use var for the type.

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox.SelectedItems` is a collection of `Object` not `ListBox`.

The easiest approach would be to hardcode it like:

```
foreach (Object item in sknBox.SelectedItems)            
{              
    Console.WriteLine((item as MyObject).Value); // or whatever it happens to be
    Console.WriteLine((item as MyObject).Label);     
}
```

If you for some reason need to be flexible I guess you could determine the type of the item and use reflection to call the getter on whatever property is assigned to ValueMember and DisplayMember.

Answer (score 0):

Based on un-lucky's answer the correct way to do it is:

```
foreach (DataRowView item in sknBox.SelectedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Row["ID"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(item.Row["Description"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Before i begin: I'm not a 100% sure on the naming of the classes in winform (specifically ListBoxItem), so make sure you look these up if needed.

You have to cast the items to the correct type before you are able to use them the way you are

```
foreach (ListBoxItem item in sknBox.SelectedItems)            
{
    if(item is DataRowView) //Check if the item can be cast to your class
    {
        DataRowView drwItem = item as DataRowView;
        Console.WriteLine(drwItem.ValueMember);
        Console.WriteLine(drwItem.DisplayMember);    
    } 
}
```

Comment: A DataRowView has no ValueMember or DisplayMember properties.